# Comparar números y si es mayor sustituirlo

Tags: java, android

`Activity` de la `Puntuación`, aquí hago la cuenta de la puntuación final y la guardo en `SharedPreferences`

```
        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        guardaPuntuacion();

        p1.setText(prefs.getString("puntos1", ""));
        p2.setText(prefs.getString("puntos2", ""));
        p3.setText(prefs.getString("puntos3", ""));

        // si está vacío = 0
        if (p1 != null && p1.getText().equals("")) {
            p1.setText("0");
        }
        if (p2 != null && p2.getText().equals("")) {
            p2.setText("0");
        }
        if (p3 != null && p3.getText().equals("")) {
            p3.setText("0");
        }
        // valores a sumar
        BigDecimal aux0 = new BigDecimal(p1.getText().toString());
        BigDecimal aux1 = new BigDecimal(p2.getText().toString());
        BigDecimal aux2 = new BigDecimal(p3.getText().toString());
        //  hago la suma:
        aux1 = aux1.add(aux0);
        aux2 = aux2.add(aux1);
        puntuaciones.setText("" + aux2);

    }
// método que guarda en `SharedPreferences` la puntuación
    public void guardaPuntuacion() {

        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        puntuaciones.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                prefs.edit().putString("ultimapunt", s.toString()).commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

En esta otra `Activity` donde cargo la puntuación:

```
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // aqui recibo la última puntuación
    ultimapunt.setText(prefs.getString("ultimapunt", ""));

    // aquí lo que quiero es siempre tener la mejor puntuación que se haya realizado

    mejorpunt.setText(prefs.getString("ultimapunt", ""));
```

Lo que he pensado es algo así como comprobar si es igual o inferior el número, si es así no hacer nada, si es superior recibirlo y guardarlo.

¿Alguna idea de como realizar eso correctamente o algo similar?

Gracias!

**EDITO1:** Lo que intento hacer es comparar

```
prefs.getString("ultimapunt", "");
```

con

```
prefs.getString("mejorpunt", "");
```

y la que sea mayor, guardarla en

```
prefs.getString("mejorpunt", "");
```

Pero se cierra la aplicación, recibo lo siguiente en `Logcat`:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView ultima, mejor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ultima = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ultima);
        mejor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mejor);

       // si esta vacío o es nulo = 0
        if (ultima != null && ultima.getText().equals("")) {
            ultima.setText("0");
        }


        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // aquí recibo la última puntuación

        ultima.setText("Ultima puntuación " + prefs.getString("ultimapunt", ""));

        // String puntuación

        String puntuacion = prefs.getString("ultimapunt", "");

        // aqui intento obtener la mejor puntuación

        mejor.setText("Mejor puntuación" + getMaxPuntuacion(puntuacion));

    }
    private String getMaxPuntuacion(String puntuacion){

        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        String puntuacionActual = prefs.getString("mejorpunt", ""); //Obtiene valor actual.
        if(Integer.parseInt(puntuacion) > Integer.parseInt(puntuacionActual)){
            prefs.edit().putString("mejorpunt", puntuacion).commit(); //Guarda nuevo valor en preferencia.
        }

        return prefs.getString("mejorpunt", ""); //obtiene el valor de la preferencia.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes la puntuación actual, comparala con la que tienes en la preferencia y guarda la que sea mayor.

Como ejemplo un método que le envias la puntuación actual y la compara con la que esta guardada en preferencia, regresa la puntuación mayor:

```
private String getMaxPuntuacion(String puntuacion){

    String puntuacionActual = prefs.getString("ultimapunt", "0"); //Obtiene valor actual.

    if(Integer.parseInt(puntuacion) > Integer.parseInt(puntuacionActual)){
        prefs.edit().putString("ultimapunt", puntuacion).commit(); //Guarda nuevo valor en preferencia.
    }

    return prefs.getString("ultimapunt", "0"); //obtiene el valor de la preferencia.

}
```

para llamarlo y asignarlo dentro del `TextView` se realiza de esta forma:

```
  // aquí lo que quiero es siempre tener la mejor puntuación que se haya realizado

    mejorpunt.setText(getMaxPuntuacion(puntuacion));
```

---

Revisando tu código marca NumberFormatException ya que trata de convertir a entero un string con valor null, la variable puntuación no esta inicializada a un valor numerico.

Simplemente valida al inicio no realice la operación o define un valor default.

```
if (puntuacion != null){
// aqui quiero tener la mejor puntuación
        mejor.setText("Mejor puntuación" + getMaxPuntuacion(puntuacion));
    } (puntuacion != null){
 // aqui quiero tener la mejor puntuación
        mejor.setText("Mejor puntuación" + getMaxPuntuacion(puntuacion));
    }
}
```

Comment: es Integer.parseInt()

Comment: es  prefs.edit().putString("ultimapunt", puntuacion).commit();

Comment: Se cierra la aplicación, he actualizado la pregunta para que puedas ver como utilizo el código y el logcat @Jorgesys

Comment: Pense este metodo se llamaria en otra parte, el problema es que al iniciar posicion tiene valor de null por lo tanto no puede convertirse a un valor numerico, puedes definir que al inicio puntuacion = "0"

Comment: Ahora recibo `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""` :/ edite la pregunta

Comment: @UserNameYo agrega como valor default "0" en los valores de la preferencia.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias !!